# magento 2 Rest APi How to use default methods

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, rest-api

Magento 2 Rest API  have many default methods.  I want to use those method and display data.

For that i have create one new user and assigned full admin access.

Trying to get the product information by SKU using default method: 
**GET  /V1/products/:sku**  which is given [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html)

Now i am running following url:

http://127.0.0.1/M224/index.php/rest/V1/products/240-LV09

When i run this url in browser it

```
<response>
    <message>Consumer is not authorized to access %resources</message>
         <parameters>
              <resources>Magento_Catalog::products</resources>
          </parameters>
</response>
```

if i use curl code like this:

```
   $apiURL="http://127.0.0.1/M224/rest/V1/integration/admin/token";

   //parameters passing with URL

     $data = array("username" => "wuser", "password" => "admin@123");

     $data_string = json_encode($data);

        $ch = curl_init($apiURL);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Content-Length: ".strlen($data_string)));


         $token = curl_exec($ch);

      //decoding generated token and saving it in a variable

      $token=  json_decode($token); 

   //decoding generated token and saving it in a variable

    $headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ".$token);

//API URL to get all Magento 2 modules

     $requestUrl='http://127.0.0.1/M224/index.php/rest/V1/products/240-LV09';


     $ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $result = curl_exec($ch);

             //decoding result

             $result=  json_decode($result);

    //printing result
            echo "<pre>";
   print_r($result);
```

Which works!

How can i access the default methods and show output?  Do i need to curl for this?

For standard practice and MobileAPP output is it good to use CURL to get there?

Is it necessary to write entire token code to get response?

using token it takes time to reponse.  Is there any better way?

Any help would be apprecaited.

Comment: @patel  please answer.

Comment: Hello Jack, Yes you need to pass Access token for Specific API, But here in your case `GET /V1/products/:sku` is accessed by admin only, that's why you're facing an error when you don't use admin's token

Comment: you can change resource for the solution.

Comment: Hey Aditya,  Thanks for reply.  But don;t you think it will give perfomance hit using token way?   Do i need to create my custom api and have anonymous resource  along with the same code to give access to guest and customer?

I want to make sure it doesn't hit performance

Comment: no i have a solution and it will not affect security and performance :)

Comment: then please answer to help me.

Comment: Hello @jack, If any answer helpful to you or solves your concern then please make right mark, it will help future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two way for this solution -

**1)** First let's go to the way where you're facing an **issue**.

- You created the admin user and give all access but still not abel to
  fetch the product details.

> So,here's is the solution and it's working fine in my Magento Version
>   2.2.4

I created an **Admin User.**

[image]

- Now i need to fetch the token for that admin user, so i did it using
  **POSTMAN**.

Url request type `POST`

```
<host>/rest/V1/integration/admin/token?username=aditya&password=aditya@123
```

**which returns token.**

`"xcph3thmoaiyt0ylm58lf2dn150qlkfr"` something like this.

---

> Now using this token we'll fetch the product by SKU for your URL.

URL request type `GET`

```
http://127.0.0.1/M224/index.php/rest/V1/products/240-LV09
```

**Payload - Headers**

```
Authorization Bearer xcph3thmoaiyt0ylm58lf2dn150qlkfr
```

> You need pass token in header, that is authntication process which
>   checks the user access in Magento.

**In response you'll get Product data**

---

**Solution 2**

This path of magento catalog API's

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/webapi.xml

To fetch products using SKU.

```
<route url="/V1/products/:sku" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products" />
        </resources>
    </route>
```

In here, there's resource defined. it means whichever user have access of `"Magento_Catalog::products"` Only those user can access this API.

```
<resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products" />
```

So, if you want to use this API for other users like customer then you can change the `resource` to `self`.

> Again it will require of token for the same, We don't compromise the
>   security of course

```
<route url="/V1/products/:sku" method="GET">
            <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
            <resources>
                <resource ref="self" />
            </resources>
        </route>
```

Now, it means we can access it.

- Using Admin's Token
- Using Admin User's Token
- Using Customer's Token.

**Yeah,You need to override this file in your module**

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/webapi.xml

and then you can access it from customer's token too.

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228815/get-all-orders-of-customer-using-customers-token-in-magento-2-api/228968#228968

Comment: Thanks for your reply aditya.  I have one question like,  i am developing this APIS to given json data for android app so to get the response using rest api I need to use token everytime?  for ex: To fetch the product i need to write the admin token code and fetch the response.   for category list i need to write the admin token code along with category code and so.  so don't you think everytime token generation will delay in response? Or there is some best methodologies?

Comment: No @jack Token is for security purpose and it's essential and every admin token expires in 4 hours and it's configurable from admin side. and you can achieve all this using customer Token too as per solution 2.

Comment: Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Yes have one query it means we need to pass token with every response we send and we need to pass the token in to response we get?    Also, Do i need to write curl code everytime to get response of all apis?  what's use of this?              <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>

Comment: Yes you need to pass token for that

Comment: `get` is a method and it's defines in this file `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`

Comment: go to this file path you will find the method `<magento-host>/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Api/ProductRepositoryInterface.php`

Comment: So now big question coming  like i have created admin token at 10:00 Am and saved it in db. now  when request from mobile will come  they will pass the same token i send to them  but after 4 hours means after 3 pm(after 4 hours of token generated)  request i will recieve will be failed so how can i maintain this communication and prevent the api response?

Comment: you can ask another question for this because it's a descriptive answer, and i am happy to answer it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79315/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-jack).

Comment: Hi Aditya,  will it be integration type ?

Comment: Sorry, not able to understand your question.

Comment: I mean to create mobile app i need to create integration first ? like shown : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html#integration-tokens      How mobile developer will use this token?

Comment: Okay got you. Here is a solution

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230005/unable-to-get-oauth-verifier-for-magento2-0/230016#230016

Comment: Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Yes,  i know that steps to generate the tokens. My question is i need to create the integration or without creating token it will work?  Is it necessary to generate the integration?  Also,  how communication will happen?  I mean how mobile developer will make request to magento?  and how i need to pass the tokens?

Comment: Yes it is necessary and i think this is your concern, `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225636/magento-2-rest-api-how-to-manage-api-authentication-lifecycle-on-mobile-device`

Comment: Can you answer this ticket:  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233485/magento-2-rest-api-get-model-data-in-response

Comment: sure let me try