# Magento 2 - Checkout Issue - Invalid state change requested -when placing an order through Authorize.net payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, authorize.net, checkout-page

When I am placing order by my payment gateway I am getting error "Invalid state change requested". when I debug the core code then I found that error is coming from plugin used by core classes.

**Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Plugin\AccessChangeQuoteControl.php**

```
public function beforeSave(CartRepositoryInterface $subject, CartInterface $quote)
{ 
    if (! $this->changeQuoteControl->isAllowed($quote)) {
        throw new StateException(__("Invalid state change requested"));
    }
}
```

Please anyone have an idea why i m facing this issue ?

Answer (score -1):

when customer does not pass the **Authentication Token** in headers.

Magento 2 **doesn't give access to Quote for users without authentication token**.

> **Please Pass authentication token Properly.**

Comment: how customer can pass Authentication token , they are placing an order through authorize.net payment gatway @Oscprofessionals

Comment: Please refer this two links 1. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html & 2. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235319/magento-2-rest-api-using-basic-auth

Comment: ok, let me check

Comment: I checked link but idid not get that what is relation of customer with access token , however if they placed an order without login @Oscprofessionals

Comment: Basically when you work with some framework, you need to work according to that. SO follow the rules of framework.

Comment: I m not using Rest Api , i think for that i need to check for authorize token this is just payment gateway inbuilt Authorize.net @Oscprofessionals